# Need help adding itemized list to tabular in template

Tags: tables, templates, document-classes

I'm trying to learn LaTeX, starting by building a resume using this template [(link)](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm#.WfN_-Pl96JA). I've had some success and I'm 90% done, but there's one issue I'm working on. In the template, there's a "skills" class (if it's called a class) which creates a 2 section tabular, the left box for the skill and the right box for description. It's intended to be used by entering a skill and then putting in a short sentence or a comma separated list to expand on the skill.

Question: What I want to do is add an itemized list in the skill detail section instead of a single line. When I do this, the formatting is not good at all. What can I do to make this work where it doesn't put in weird spacing and keeps the left box (skill) top aligned? I don't really understand the class, I would like to understand how to modify it to suit my needs.

[Here's a sample file with everything invalidated](https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApIxGe4GMyrAgosOn9CfXai_omdNyw)

Thanks in advance!

**Class file:**

```
% Define an environment for cvskill
\newenvironment{cvskills}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-2.0mm}
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{1ex}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} r L{\textwidth * \real{0.9}}}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
}
% Define a line of cv information(skill)
% Usage: \cvskill{<type>}{<skillset>}
\newcommand*{\cvskill}[2]{%
    \skilltypestyle{#1} & \skillsetstyle{#2} \\
}
```

**Intended Use:**

```
\cvsection{Skills}

\begin{cvskills}

  \cvskill
    {My First Skill} % Category
    {Comma, Seperated, List, Of, Items, Works, As, Intended} % Skills

% Continue Items.....

\end{cvskills}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**My attempt at entering a list:**

```
\begin{cvskills}

  \cvskill
    {My First Skill} % Category
    {
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2ex, nosep, noitemsep, label={\Large$\cdot$}]    
        \item {Using lists doesn't work correctly}
        \item {As you can see}
        \item {In this example}
    \end{itemize}
    } % Skills

% Continue Items.....

\end{cvskills}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: A full compilable code would be nice…

Comment: What you think does not work, is quite a common issue. As this is only a tabular you might want to have a look at the questions about the vertical orientation in tabulars.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Rather than posting links, which may disappear next week making the question opaque, and incomplete code snippets can you please post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. The code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier to help you and, hence, much more likely that some one will.

Answer (score 2):

Add `\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}`  to your preamble. This will issue a warning.

Use the following in your document:

```
\newcommand{\cvitem}[1]{\bullet~#1\par}

\begin{cvskills}
  \cvskill
      {My First Skill}
      {%
\cvitem{Using lists doesn't work correctly}
\cvitem{As you can see}
\cvitem{In this example}
} % Skills
\end{cvskills}
```

---

Disclaimer: This will affect *all* instances that use the `L` columntype.